# Несколько БД для сайта

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Всем добрый день! Задумался над тем как сделать несколько БД для одного сайта. Что бы базы синхронизировались между собой и в случае если одна не доступна то данные подтягивались с другой. И если изменения были внесены в одну пока другая не работает что бы в нее автоматически догрузились данные. Кто делал? Кто знает? Кто подскажет?

Comment: для начала стоит прочитать про то, что такое [репликация](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html).

Comment: ...механизм работы каковой, собственно, в вопросе и описан. Ну, не считая failover'а на запасной сервер.